# Spawning more than one thread in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have an application that trawls for files on a network and then uploads them to a cloud service. It's not the fastest thing so I started to wonder whether I should finally try to get my head around threading.

What I want to do is have one thread that crawls the network looking for files to process and adding them to a queue, and then a number of uploader threads that read the queue and if there's work to do, they pull the task off the queue.

The reason for having more than one thread handling the uploading is that this part of the process is slow and a whole batch is likely to take days or even weeks based on initial tests. At the moment and without any threading, I have routine that finds all the files to upload and then an uploader routine uploads them.

So I'm assuming that if I can somehow have a single queue/list that is accessible to all threads, the thread that adds files to the list can be doing that whilst multiple uploader threads are pulling them off the list and processing them individually. It sounds like it should be possible but I can't see how. BTW most of the 'Sleep' statements in this test code are purely there for test purposes.

I found this sample which was helpful: https://cjhaas.com/2009/06/25/creating-a-simple-multi-threaded-vb-net-application/

And I based my test project on that.

The code below is complete but you will need to create a form with a progress bar, button and the labels. It builds and works fine and includes 3 threads, one for adding content to the queue (dummy data at the moment), one that processes the queue (just has a timer for now) and one to monitor the progress and update a progress bar.

I'm pleased that I got this far as I'M A COMPLETE NOVICE, but I can't work out what I would need to do to this code to make it spawn more that one worker thread AND be able to share the same queue; I tried peeling the queue out as a separate class but there were issues getting the thread to communicate with the queue class (I failed to make a note of the problems otherwise I would have added them for completeness).

Are there some easy changes that could be made to this to allow me to have more than one uploading worker thread? Or is there a better example I should look to adapt for my needs?

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Threading


Public Class Form1
    Private MonitorThread As Thread
    Private WorkerThread As Thread
    Private QueueThread As Thread
    Private W As Worker
    Private Delegate Sub UpdateUIDelegate()
    Private Delegate Sub WorkerDoneDelegate()

    Private Sub Monitor()
        Do While WorkerThread.ThreadState <> ThreadState.Stopped    'Loop until the Worker thread (and thus the Worker object's Start() method) is done
            UpdateUI()                                      'Update the progress bar with the current value
            Thread.Sleep(250)                                       'Sleep the monitor thread otherwise we'll be wasting CPU cycles updating the progress bar a million times a second
        Loop
        WorkerDone()                                                'If we're here, the worker object is done, call a method to do some cleanup
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateUI()
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then                                                           'See if we need to cross threads
            Me.Invoke(New UpdateUIDelegate(AddressOf UpdateUI), New Object() {})    'If so, have the UI thread call this method for us
        Else
            'Me.ProgressBar1.Value = curIndex                                                'Otherwise just update the progress bar
            'Me.ProgressBar1.Value = W.CurRun                                                'Otherwise just update the progress bar

            Me.ProgressBar1.Maximum = W.Qtotal
            Me.ProgressBar1.Value = W.Qtotal - W.Remaining                                                'Otherwise just update the progress bar


            Me.Lbl_CurrentRun.Text = (W.Qtotal - W.Remaining).ToString
            Me.Lbl_Total.Text = "Total = " + W.Qtotal.ToString
            Me.Lbl_Remaining.Text = "Remaining = " + W.Remaining.ToString
            Me.Lbl_Date.Text = "Date = " + W.MSGdate.ToLongTimeString
            Me.Lbl_Path.Text = "Message = " + W.MSGpath
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub WorkerDone()
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then                                                           'See if we need to cross threads
            Me.Invoke(New WorkerDoneDelegate(AddressOf WorkerDone))                         'If so, have the UI thread call this method for us
        Else
            Me.Button1.Enabled = True                                                       'Otherwise just update the button

            Me.ProgressBar1.Value = W.Qtotal - W.Remaining                                  ' Update these to ensure they show the final data
            Me.Lbl_CurrentRun.Text = (W.Qtotal - W.Remaining).ToString
            Me.Lbl_Remaining.Text = "Remaining = " + W.Remaining.ToString
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Button1.Enabled = False                      'Disable the button
        W = New Worker()                                'Create our Worker object

        QueueThread = New Thread(AddressOf W.PopulateQueue) 'Create a queue thread and tel it where to start when we call the start method
        WorkerThread = New Thread(AddressOf W.Start)    'Create our Worker thread and tell it that when we start it it should call our Worker's Start() method
        MonitorThread = New Thread(AddressOf Monitor)   'Create our Monitor thread and tell it that when we start it it should call this class's Monitor() method

        QueueThread.Start()                             'Start the queue thread which adds items to the queue
        'Wait a while to allow some items to be added to the queue
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        WorkerThread.Start()                            'Start the worker thread
        MonitorThread.Start()                           'Start the monitor thread which updates the progress bar
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Worker
    Private iQtotal As Integer = 0            ' The total items processed
    Private iRemaining As Integer           ' Remaining items in the queue
    Dim SortedList As New List(Of sMSG)()

    Public ReadOnly Property Qtotal() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.iQtotal
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Remaining() As Integer
        Get
            'SortedList.TrimExcess()
            Return SortedList.Count
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property MSGdate() As Date
        Get
            Return SortedList.FirstOrDefault.mDate
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property MSGpath() As String
        Get
            Return SortedList.FirstOrDefault.sFullpath
        End Get
    End Property


    Public Sub PopulateQueue()
        Dim tempMSG As New sMSG         'We will assemble the message in here before adding to the queue

        tempMSG.sFullpath = "Path"
        tempMSG.sLocation = "Location"
        tempMSG.sLocationGUID = "GUID"
        tempMSG.sLocationServerID = "666"

        ' This loop adds test data to the queue. It will be replaced with file system crawler
        For i = 1 To 50
            tempMSG.mDate = Date.Now
            tempMSG.sFullpath = "Path " + i.ToString
            SortedList.Add(tempMSG)
            iQtotal = iQtotal + 1
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
            SortList()
        Next i
    End Sub
    Public Sub SortList()
        SortedList = (From obj In SortedList Select obj Order By obj.mDate Descending).ToList()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
    Public Sub Start()
        Dim nextMSG As sMSG

        While SortedList.Count > 0
            nextMSG = SortedList.FirstOrDefault             'Get the first item off the list
            '' Do the upload of it...
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(150)
            SortedList.Remove(nextMSG)    'Remove it from the queue
        End While

    End Sub
End Class


Public Class sMSG
    Public sFullpath As String
    Public sLocation As String
    Public sLocationGUID As String
    Public sLocationServerID As String
    Public mDate As Date
End Class
```

#######

So following the advice from Craig and djv I started to look at changing the code to use the **ConcurrentBag** object.

Unfortunately there is no way to remove items from the list/queue with the **ConcurrentBag**. Fortunately I came across the **ConcurrentQueue** and this works just fine.

The following code is not pretty **but it works** and in my tests I was able to see the performance improvements from the additional threads. It needs more work to perhaps manage how many threads are spawned but that's for later.

My thanks to by @Craig and @djv for trying to help and I hope this is of use to someone.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Collections.Concurrent

Public Class Form1
    Private MonitorThread As Thread
    Private WorkerThread1 As Thread
    Private WorkerThread2 As Thread
    Private WorkerThread3 As Thread
    Private QueueThread As Thread

    Private Delegate Sub UpdateUIDelegate()
    Private Delegate Sub BatchIsDOneDelegate()

    Private tStart As Date

    Private cq As New ConcurrentQueue(Of sMSG)
    Public iQTotal As Integer


    Private Sub Monitor()
        Do While cq.Count > 0    'Loop until the queue is empty
            UpdateUI()                                      'Update the progress bar with the current value
            Thread.Sleep(250)                                       'Sleep the monitor thread otherwise we'll be wasting CPU cycles updating the progress bar a million times a second
        Loop
        BatchIsDOne()                                                'If we're here, the batch is done, call a method to do some cleanup
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateUI()
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then                                                           'See if we need to cross threads
            Me.Invoke(New UpdateUIDelegate(AddressOf UpdateUI), New Object() {})    'If so, have the UI thread call this method for us
        Else
            Me.ProgressBar1.Maximum = iQTotal
            Me.ProgressBar1.Value = iQTotal - cq.Count                                                'Otherwise just update the progress bar

            Me.Lbl_CurrentRun.Text = (iQTotal - cq.Count).ToString
            Me.Lbl_Total.Text = "Total = " + iQTotal.ToString
            Me.Lbl_Remaining.Text = "Remaining = " + cq.Count.ToString
            Me.Lbl_Elapsed.Text = "Elapsed = " + (Date.Now - tStart).ToString
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub BatchIsDOne()
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then                                                           'See if we need to cross threads
            Me.Invoke(New BatchIsDOneDelegate(AddressOf BatchIsDOne))                         'If so, have the UI thread call this method for us
        Else
            Me.Button1.Enabled = True                                                       'Otherwise just update the button

            Me.ProgressBar1.Value = iQTotal - cq.Count                                  ' Update these to ensure they show the final data
            Me.Lbl_CurrentRun.Text = (iQTotal - cq.Count).ToString
            Me.Lbl_Remaining.Text = "Remaining = " + cq.Count.ToString
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Button1.Enabled = False                      'Disable the button
        tStart = Date.Now                               'Note the start time


        QueueThread = New Thread(AddressOf PopulateQueue) 'Create a queue thread and tel it where to start when we call the start method
        WorkerThread1 = New Thread(AddressOf ProcessNextMSG)    'Create 1st Worker thread and tell it that when we start it it should call our Worker's Start() method
        WorkerThread2 = New Thread(AddressOf ProcessNextMSG)    'Create 2nd Worker thread and tell it that when we start it it should call our Worker's Start() method
        WorkerThread3 = New Thread(AddressOf ProcessNextMSG)    'Create 2nd Worker thread and tell it that when we start it it should call our Worker's Start() method

        MonitorThread = New Thread(AddressOf Monitor)   'Create our Monitor thread and tell it that when we start it it should call this class's Monitor() method

        QueueThread.Start()                             'Start the queue thread which adds items to the queue
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)               'Wait a while to allow some items to be added to the queue just for test purposes
        WorkerThread1.Start()                            'Start the worker thread
        WorkerThread2.Start()                            'Start the worker thread
        WorkerThread3.Start()                            'Start the worker thread

        MonitorThread.Start()                           'Start the monitor thread which updates the progress bar
    End Sub

    Public Sub PopulateQueue()
        Dim tempMSG As New sMSG         'We will assemble the message in here before adding to the queue

        tempMSG.sFullpath = "Path"
        tempMSG.sLocation = "Location"
        tempMSG.sLocationGUID = "GUID"
        tempMSG.sLocationServerID = "666"


        ' This loop adds test data to the queue. It will be replaced with a file system crawler
        For i = 1 To 50
            tempMSG.mDate = Date.Now
            tempMSG.sFullpath = "Path " + i.ToString
            cq.Enqueue(tempMSG)                 ' Add the MSG to the queue
            iQTotal = iQTotal + 1
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
        Next i
    End Sub

    Public Sub ProcessNextMSG()
        Dim nextMSG As New sMSG

        ' While the queue is not empty, take a message from the top and process it
        While cq.IsEmpty = False
            If cq.TryDequeue(nextMSG) = False Then
                ' It failed to get next message from queue
            Else
                '' Do the uploading of it...
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(350)              'Just to mimmick the uploading for now
            End If
        End While
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class sMSG
        Public sFullpath As String
        Public sLocation As String
        Public sLocationGUID As String
        Public sLocationServerID As String
        Public mDate As Date
    End Class
```

Comment: I didn't see a declaration for your sorted list, but note that as soon as you are potentially accessing and modifying from different threads, you need to be using the `Concurrent` versions which are designed to work correctly under such usage.

Comment: In this scheme, to make more workers, you... just do it?  You could have the workers kept in a `List(Of Thread)` instead of a scalar variable.

Comment: `Class Worker` declares private instance member `Dim SortedList As New List(Of sMSG)()`, so it's just a regular List, the same instance being used by both PopulateQueue and Start inside Worker. As @Craig said you could try using `Private SortedList As New System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag(Of sMSG)()`

Comment: Also I don't see how you can leverage multi-threading efficiently here. You populate the list then wait 500ms, why? Because you are waiting for the list to be entirely populated? If you don't and the list is still being populated when Start runs then Start will process everything that is currently in the list and potentially miss new items. Really, you should try to run these two threads sequentially, or just run it in a single thread. Now, if you do need to upload partially, and process partially, and repeat, then you could restructure the threads into lists of each and spawn with a timer

Comment: Thanks for the replies Craig and djv. I'm struggling with the advice here as I'm not sure how I implement it. 

Are you saying that rather than declaring 'SortedList' inside the 'Worker' class, I should declare it more globally, for example at the head of the 'Form1' class and as 'Private SortedList As New System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag(Of sMSG)()' , and that this would then enable me to start multiple worker threads that can then access the 'SortedList'?

Some code snippets would be really appreciated as I really am a complete novice and am learning by trial and error.

Comment: @MaxHeadroom you have once instance of Worker, so it's using the same instance of the list, which is fine as long as you declare as a ConcurrentBag. Try that first

Comment: Why do you need two threads to do the populate and process?

Comment: Thanks Craig and @djv. I had another go at this but with the `ConcurrentQueue` class. I have updated my posting to both provide more context and show where I have now got and why I still need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that a ConcurrentQueue was what I needed and have pasted the full working code into the thread above. Thanks to both @Craig and @djv for trying to help.